# Export single band from a multiband stacked raster with rasterio

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

I have been trying to break down my multi-band raster into individual bands with rasterio and I am getting this error:

`ValueError: Source shape (11356, 9488) is inconsistent with given indexes 1`

here's the code:

```
import os
import rasterio


 src = rasterio.open(wv_tif)
    for band in range(1, src.count):
        single_band = src.read(band)

        # get the output name
        out_name = os.path.basename(wv_tif)
        file, ext = os.path.splitext(out_name)
        name = file + "_" + "B" + str(band) + ".tif"
        out_img = os.path.join(folder, name)

        print(out_img + " done")

        # Copy the metadata
        out_meta = src.meta.copy()

        out_meta.update({"count": 1})

        # save the clipped raster to disk
        with rasterio.open(out_img, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
            dest.write(single_band)
```

I have no idea what is going wrong

Comment: Note you need to use `for band in range(1, src.count + 1):` or you'll miss the last band as the  `range(start, stop)` function only returns values >= start and **< stop**. E.g. if you have a 4 band raster `range(1, 4)` will only have values `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: right! good catch! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling rasterio to write a dataset so it's expecting an array shape of  `(bands, rows, cols)`, but you're passing a single band, an array shape of `(rows, cols)`.

Either reshape your array:

```
dest.write(single_band[np.newaxis,...])`
```

Or tell rasterio to write a single band:

```
dest.write(single_band, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and with some changes I reached one script that worked fine.

```
import os
import rasterio
```

Defining different objects to be used:,

```
src = 'C:/home/User/Documents/file.tif'
src2 = rasterio.open('C:/home/User/Documents/file.tif')
folder = 'C:/home/User/Documents'

for band in range(1, src2.count +1): #The +1 allows the writing of the last band
        single_band = src2.read(band)

        # get the output name
        out_name = os.path.basename(src)
        file, ext = os.path.splitext(out_name)
        name = file + "_" + "B" + str(band) + ".tif"
        out_img = os.path.join(folder, name)

        print(out_img + " done")

        # Copy the metadata
        out_meta = src2.meta.copy()

        out_meta.update({"count": 1})

        # save the clipped raster to disk
        with rasterio.open(out_img, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
            dest.write(single_band, 1)
```